# install google map.jar to Moto Phone

Tags: android, root-access

I tried to install an app using com.google.android.maps library on Moto XT681 Phone. Eclipse failed, reporting :

```
    Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
```

By examining the Logcat, it states as following

```
Package com.xxxx.xxxx requires unavailable shared library com.google.android.maps; failing!
```

I tried to push the maps.jar file into the phone using ddms. However, it said: transfer eror: Permission denied. I guess it is because the ddms didn't connect the phone as root. I also tried using adb command, however, there was something wierd, when I tried the command adb devices, it always reboot the adb server, and could not get the device in the list?

So anyone can suggest a way out?

Comment: @KazekageGaara look at the answers here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134070/186983

Comment: @Matsemann I doubt if this is the case for the OP. Look at his questions, they have been answered by experts and seemed to have solved his purpose on occasions. It's the indifferent attitude that needs to be corrected at times.

Comment: Anyway, thanks Kazekage for his suggestion, I think I know your point. Maybe, I hope to get perfect answer. However, I do get some valuable info from their answers, I will give credit for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY

The ROM you have installed on that device -- whether from the manufacturer or a ROM mod that you put on it -- lacks the Google Maps add-on for Android.

> I tried to push the maps.jar file into the phone using ddms. However, it said: transfer eror: Permission denied. I guess it is because the ddms didn't connect the phone as root. I also tried using adb command, however, there was something wierd, when I tried the command adb devices, it always reboot the adb server, and could not get the device in the list?

The Google Maps add-on for Android comes with the firmware (a.k.a., device ROM). If your device lacks this add-on, buy a device that has it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your kind reply, However I hope I can get rid of the problem without changing the phone!